# How to set size on multiselect-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-multiselect

I want an open dropdown as it usually works in html with the keyword `size` inside the `select` tag. Haven't found a solution yet.

My HTML Code so far:

```
<select id="fileDropdown" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
   <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

My JavaScript Code so far:

```
$('#fileDropdown').multiselect({
   buttonText: function(options) {
           return "Search or select";
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this for size your multiple select

```
<select name='courses' multiple="multiple" size='8'>
   <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
   <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```